# Why is there no empty set in a π-system?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let us define a π-system on a set $\Omega$ as a collection $\mathscr A$ of certain subsets of $\Omega$ having two properties: $\mathscr A$ being non-empty and being closed under finite intersections (meaning that if $A, B \in \mathscr A$, then $A \bigcap B \in \mathscr A$ as well).

However, the π-system page in Wikipedia (which is not really the best source but it did make me curious) has the following statement under the definitions section:

"A non-empty family of sets has the finite intersection property if and only if the π-system it generates does not contain the empty set as an element."

When I think about it, some collection of subsets of $\Omega$ is bound to contain sets that do not intersect, hence producing an empty set for the intersection, such as the collection below.

$\mathscr C = \{A\},\{B\},\{A,B\}$

Can someone enlightment me with this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello, as you have seen, $\mathscr C$ is not closed under finite intersections (because $\{A\} \cap \{B\} = \emptyset$) and the $\pi$-system it generates will contain $\emptyset$ so this is coherent. I'm not sure if I have understood your question.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the Wikipedia comment if I consider the title of your question. A $\pi$-system can contain the empty set, but if it is generated by a family of sets, then the Wikipedia remark is that this family is not stable by finite intersections.

Comment: Two different definitions 1) Pi-system - any non-empty collection of sets closed under finite intersections.  2) Pi-system with *finite-intersection-property* - a Pi-system not containing the empty set.

Comment: @ChadK Now I get it. I was confused with the definition as I thought that they were one and the same. Thank you so much for the clarification. NaNoS' comment made sense as well after this realization.